# How to remove home back arrow spacing in vertical 2nd line below the first vertical line in toolbar in android

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar, spacing

How to remove home back arrow spacing in vertical 2nd line below the first vertical line in `toolbar` in android.

This is my code please need solution for this thanks!

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarHome"`enter code here`
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/headerbackground"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarThemeWhiteBlack"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp">
```

.......
......

```
        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

how to remove this space which I mentioned ?

[image: image of space which I mentioned]

Answer (score 1):

To remove the left margin you can simply add XML attributes to remove content insets.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarHome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"

    android:background="@drawable/headerbackground"
    ...
 />
```